# Return value of interface method (no params) is acquired asynchronously. Can it be implemented?

Tags: java, asynchronous, interface, callback

I've been given an interface which is like this:

```
MyInterface {
    List<FirebaseVisionFace> getFaceList();
}
```

I have to implement it in a class (let's call it `MyFirebaseFaceClass`) in such a way that we can then do

```
List<FirebaseVisionFace> faceList = myFirebaseFaceClass.getFaceList()
```

The problem is that to get this list of faces, the following is required:

```
Task<List<FirebaseVisionFace>> result =
    detector.detectInImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionFace>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces) {
                            // Task completed successfully
                            // ...
                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(
                    new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // Task failed with an exception
                            // ...
                        }
                    });
```

Is it possible to implement this `getFaceList()` method without passing in a callback as a parameter and using the callback to get the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).  In an implementation of your interface:

```
class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {
  @Override
  List<FirebaseVisionFace> getFaceList() {
    final CompletableFuture<List<FirebaseVisionFace>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    final DetectorOfSomeKindYouDidNotSpecifyAbove detector = // ... get detector
    detector.detectInImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionFace>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces) {
                            // Task completed successfully
                            future.complete(faces);
                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(
                    new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // Task failed with an exception
                            future.completeExceptionally(e);
                        }
                    });
    try {
      return future.get(); // blocks until completion by one of the listeners above
    } catch (final RuntimeException throwMe) {
      throw throwMe;
    } catch (final InterruptedException interruptedException) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      throw new IllegalStateException(interruptedException.getMessage(), interruptedException);
    } catch (final Exception everythingElse) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(everythingElse.getMessage(), everythingElse);
    }
  }
}
```

My error handling code above is stupid for brevity.  All code above is untested and written off the cuff.  I am assuming that the listeners are called when all discovery is done, and are called once.  I'm also assuming that only one of the listeners is called, not both of them.  I'm also assuming that they're called by another thread.

Lastly, do note that (as you seem to be aware) an interface like the kind you're trying to implement will inherently remove all benefits of the asynchronicity taking place in its underlying implementation.

Hopefully this will at least point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

If you work with asynchronous tasks in Java, you can't avoid callbacks. You use Task class that uses callbacks a lot. If you don't like this syntax, you can use lambdas:

```java
Task<List<FirebaseVisionFace>> result = 
    detector.detectInImage(image)
        .addOnSuccessListener((List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces) -> {
             // Task completed successfully
        })
        .addOnFailureListener((@NotNull Exception e) -> {
             // Task failed with an exception
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer :) The particular code snippet you provided wasn't an issue for me, but knowing that the callback would be necessary is a great help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid callbacks, but you can use method references as callbacks, so the whole code looks cleaner:

```
class MyFirebaseFaceClass implements MyInterface {
    List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces;
    Exception exception;
    boolean done = false;

    // Task completed successfully
    private synchronized void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces) {
        this.faces = faces;
        done = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    // Task failed with an exception
    private synchronized void onError(Exception exception) {
        this.exception = exception;
        done = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    List<FirebaseVisionFace> getFaceList() {
         detector.detectInImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this::onSuccess)
            .addOnFailureListener(this::onError);
         synchronized (this) {
            while (!done) {
                wait();
            }
            if (exception == null) {
                return faces;
            } else {
                throw new ExcecutionException(exception);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this interesting alternative, Alexei.